# phpMyAdmin - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm in a CentOS VM and I can login to IP/phpmyadmin and execute queries.

If I want to do a mysqldump in terminal though, I get this:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I edited /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'mypassword';
```

Restarted mysqld, same error.

I even tried running a query:

```
mysql>UPDATE mysql.user 
->SET Password=PASSWORD("*******")
->WHERE User="root";
mysql>FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

### What else can I try? Thanks.

Also, I can't edit privileges once I'm in phpMyAdmin: http://screencast.com/t/G9belKdy5mzD

SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost'

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*52DD4BE9BA633906276F1950905A9013E2A77FE3' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Comment: SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';  and post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use -p parameter even if you are logged in

```
mysqldump -p database > file.sql
```

Comment: This solved my mysqldump issue. Fantastic! Thanks. I'll  report the grants above.